# Error in fresh installation of backpack for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I installed **backpack** on a fresh installation of laravel5.6 and when I go to **/admin** it displays this **Error :**

> ReflectionException (-1) Class App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin does
>   not exist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Could be many things: A) it was not installed correctly B) your webserver did not pick up the change C) maybe you need to re-generate your autoload files (might be using a classmap) (`composer dump`)

Comment: i did the composer dump already, still no change and i have tried reinstalling on another laravel application, same problem

Comment: Sounds like thr CheckIfAdmin middleware has not been published, or your Laravel install doesn’t pick it up. Please go to app/Http/Middleware and see if CheckIfAdmin.php is there. If it is, run composer dump-autoload.

Comment: If it isn’t there, please go theough the Backpack installation steps one more time.

Comment: If you haven't edited anything on your own, please report this to whoever provided the repository you are using. Without sharing code, it's impossible to provide help

Answer (score 2):

For those googling this issue, this happened when  I tried to run backpack admin without having called the builtin install for backpack

```
php artisan backpack:install
```

If for some reason you  have to publish these middleware I'd suggest you call

```
php artisan backpack:publish-middleware
```

because with the current version coping the middleware gave me a duplicated class name exception, but calling this worked well